# Как программно установить фокус в поле "Куда" панели маршрутизации?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня карта размещена в модальном окне бустрап и по умолчанию не винда. При нажатии кнопки "Рассчитать калькулятором" всплывает модальное окно расчета стоимости доставки взятый из примера
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator/
Но если бы карта была сразу видна, то поле "Куда" сразу было бы в фокусе. Но так как пользователь не понимает что делать, мне надо чтобы это поле сразу было активно, потому что при этом курсор принимает другой вид и пользователь может сразу тыкнуть на карте на место назначения. В виду того что на телефоне место мало для дополнительных инструкций нужно решить мне эту задачу. Всё это я делаю под телефон. Под десктоп проблем нет, там есть куда вставить инструкцию, но все же нужно максимально автоматизировать процесс указания адреса доставки

Answer (score 0):

Контрол можно сделать активным вызовом **focus()**. Но имейте в виду, что метод не описан, а потому не разрешён пользовательским соглашением и может быть в любой момент изменён или удалён, хотя сейчас вполне работоспособен.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
            zoom: 9,
                        controls: ['routePanelControl']
        });
  
    var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');
  // Отслеживаем смещение карты
    myMap.events.add('boundschange', function () {
  // Возвращаем фокус на панель для построения машрутов
            control.routePanel.focus();
    });
}
```

```css
html, body, #map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&apikey=" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Разве что это прокидывается нативный метод JS, быть может? Тогда он не может запрещаться Яндексом и должен работать всегда. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus